# AngularJS - pagination - add active class to current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbuchanan/eqtxLkbg/4/

I have the functionality I need working, except I need to add an active class to the current page when cycling through the pages:

```
<ul class="pagination-controle pagination">
    <li>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-hide="curPage == 0"
        ng-click="curPage = curPage-1"> &lt; PREV</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span ng-click="curPage = curPage - 2" ng-hide="curPage < datalists.length/pageSize - 1">{{curPage - 1}}</span>
        <span ng-click="curPage = curPage - 1" ng-hide="curPage === 0">{{curPage}}</span>
        <span>{{curPage + 1}}</span>
        <span ng-click="curPage = curPage + 1" ng-hide="curPage >= datalists.length/pageSize - 1">{{curPage + 2}}</span>
        <span ng-click="curPage = curPage + 2" ng-hide="curPage >= datalists.length/pageSize - 2">{{curPage + 3}}</span>
        <span ng-click="curPage = curPage + 3" ng-hide="curPage !== 0 ">{{curPage + 4}}</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
        ng-hide="curPage >= datalists.length/pageSize - 1"
        ng-click="curPage = curPage+1">NEXT &gt;</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: there is angular bootstrap pagination already. if you still want to use your own, you can take a look how the implemented the active class and mimic it into you controller. 

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination

Comment: @alsafoo i'll check it out. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, based on the existing logic, that the first visible span is always the current page. So I can simply apply an active class on that element at all times. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbuchanan/eqtxLkbg/5/

```
    <span class="active pagination-button">{{curPage + 1}}</span>
```